# Why is my code failing the following test?

Tags: java

So my code is supposed to return the following:

Hounsfield units are mapped by the window to a real number in the range of {@code 0} to {@code 1}. A Hounsfield unit with a value less than lo is mapped to the value {@code 0}. A Hounsfield unit with a value greater than hi is mapped to the value {@code 1}. A Hounsfield unit with a value v between lo and hi is mapped to the value: (v - lo) / width.

I have passed all of the previous JUnit tests and assume my public double map(Hounsfield f) is the problem?

I have completed another class called Hounsfield and it outputs the value v they are asking for.

```
public class HounsfieldWindow {
private int level, width;

public HounsfieldWindow(int level, int width) {
    setLevel(level);
    setWidth(width);
}

public HounsfieldWindow() {
    this(0, 400); 
}

public int getLevel() {
    return level;
}

public int setLevel(int level) {
    if (level < Hounsfield.MIN_VALUE || level > Hounsfield.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    int data = this.level;
    this.level = level;
    return data;
}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public int setWidth(int width) {
    if (width <= 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    int data = this.width;
    this.width = width;
    return data;
}

public double getLowerBound() {
    return level - (width / 2);
}

public double getUpperBound() {
    return level + (width / 2);
}

public double map(Hounsfield f) {

    int hounsfieldUnitVal = f.get();
    System.out.println(hounsfieldUnitVal);
    if (hounsfieldUnitVal < getLowerBound()) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (hounsfieldUnitVal > getUpperBound()) {
        return 1;
    }
    return (hounsfieldUnitVal - getLowerBound()) / width;
}
```

I assume that the failing of assertEquals means that my return result is wrong?

The actual test is the following:

```
@Test
public void test11_map() {
    assumeTrue("test requires a correct implementation of HounsfieldWindow(int, int)", IS_CTOR_OK);

    // tests Hounsfield units in windows of various widths and levels
    final int[] WIDTH = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100, 255 };
    final int[] LEVEL = { -800, -1, 1, 750 };

    for (int level : LEVEL) {
        for (int width : WIDTH) {
            // make a window to call map on
            HounsfieldWindow w = new HounsfieldWindow(level, width);

            // expected values map should return
            double[] EXP = HounsfieldWindowTest.mapValues(width);

            for (int i = 0; i < EXP.length; i++) {
                // Hounsfield unit to map
                Hounsfield h = new Hounsfield(level - width / 2 + i);

                // the expected return value of map(h)
                double exp = EXP[i];

                // the actual value returned by map(h)
                double got = w.map(h);

                // make an error message in case the test fails
                String error = String.format(
                        "map(%s) failed to return the correct value for a window with level %s, width %s", h.get(),
                        level, width);

                // assert that exp equals got
                assertEquals(error, exp, got, 1e-9);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used the debugger or logging to check actual values for `exp` and `got`?

Comment: Well, in that case it's all the more important to debug your code. There might be a small error somewhere that's easiest to spot by stepping through your code with a debugger (knowing how to do that is an essential skill anyway).

Comment: I see `width / 2` in a lot of places.  Are you aware that an int divided by an int produces an int?  If `width` is 5, `width / 2` is exactly 2.  However, `(double) width / 2` is 2.5, because division involving a `double` will perform floating-point division and will always return a double.  Similarly, `width / 2.0` is 2.5, since `2.0` is a `double` literal.

Comment: Thank you! This worked and I am new to Java so I will be sure to remember this!